# GreenDao Generator class is giving error while generating the model and dao classes.

Tags: android, orm, dao, noclassdeffounderror, greendao

Whenever I am trying to run the Greendao Example generator class to generate my model and dao classes, it is giving me the following error. I am not able to understand what is wrong. I am new in Android as well as in using Greendao. Please help me.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/template/ObjectWrapper
at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.gentest.ExampleDaoGenerator.main(ExampleDaoGenerator.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.template.ObjectWrapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Comment: The stracktrace says that the Class freemarker.template.ObjectWrapper can't be found. You have to add the Freemarker library to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I let you a very good [tutorial](http://www.devteam83.com/en/blog/detail/tutorial-greendao-from-scratch-part-1) (it has two parts) who explain how to configure the projects from scratch. 
I already tested using the greenDao 2.0 and works fine!

Also you have the classic [Get Started](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/how-to-get-started/), and his [project on github](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO).

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the freemarker library to your project.

found here: freemarker.org

Comment: Have added freemaker.jar in my project libs folder.Got same error